# OpenJFX 14 TextField NodeOrientation RIGHT_TO_LEFT Cannot Move Cursor Via Keyboard on Windows 10

Tags: java, javafx

I am on a Windows 10 machine with Oracle JDK 14 and OpenJFX 14 installed. When keyboard focus is in a `TextField` control and that control's orientation is right-to-left, pressing the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard does not move the cursor within the `TextField`. Here is a simple program that demonstrates the problem.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTxtFld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField txtFld = new TextField("sampler");
        txtFld.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        Group root = new Group(txtFld);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Run the above code and then simply try to move the cursor by pressing the arrow keys on the keyboard. When I do it, the cursor does not move. I can move the cursor by clicking the mouse within the text contents of the `TextField`. Also the up-arrow key moves the cursor to before the letter *s*, i.e. the start of the text and the down-arrow key moves the cursor to after the letter *r* but pressing the left- and right-arrow keys does not move the cursor at all. Note that if the orientation is left-to-right the arrow keys do move the cursor.

When I print out the Java [System] properties, I see the following.

```
user.language  en
user.country   US
```

I Googled for the terms ***javafx textfield cursor does not move*** but I only saw results that talk about manipulating the cursor via code and not via user actions.

### EDIT

Perhaps someone can verify whether this problem also exists in earlier JavaFX versions?

## UPDATE

For anyone interested, the issue appears to be resolved in [JavaFX 15 Windows x64 SDK](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

Comment: looks like a major bug to me (plus extending selection is working ... into the wrong direction) Please consider reporting it (there is some ongoing work on rtl issues, there's a chance to get it fixed right away :)

Comment: @kleopatra Done. Bug ID is 9064491

Comment: thanks :) The report is now visible as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242616 - marked as regression and increased priority to make sure somebody will look into it soon :)

Comment: hmm ... strange: the issue is not yet fixed and I can't reproduce the now-working .. caret still doesn't move with the current dev

Comment: I discovered that [ZuluFX](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zulufx-faq/), from _Azul_, does not have this bug.